# xterm select text with keyboard that is anywhere in window

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, xterm, selection

Is there a way to select and copy text anywhere in terminal(xterm) window(that is, not only current shell line, but also output from previous commands) using only keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

XTerm version from end of 2013 cannot do that, unfortunately.

You can use tmux or screen to copy text, as akira reponded.

Also you can copy output of the last command to X selection easily with:

```
!! | xsel -bi
```

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312213/how-do-i-copy-text-from-my-xterm-without-a-mouse

Comment: Splendid! You got a +1 just for posting that link, because all this stuff here is pretty useless for me. However, Q312213 had exactly what I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) and [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Copy) (shell multiplexers) both have a copy-mode, which you can enter via keyboard, move around the cursor via keys .. and select text via the cursor. naturally, you can scroll back in the output buffer.

i don't know a pure xterm-solution, maybe something like gnome-terminal etc will do it (allthough i doubt it, they are even more fancy than xterm :))

Comment: I know and use tmux, though here I'm looking for terminal only solution. I would fall back  to multiplexers only if there is no solution.